# Go 1.5 to 1.6: import cycle not allowed

Tags: go

I'm trying to migrate from Go 1.5.3 to Go 1.6 and for some packages I encounter "import cycle not allowed" error, when I'm trying to build them for 1.6 .

e.g for building the golint tool I'm getting:

```
import cycle not allowed
package github.com/golang/lint/golint
    imports flag
    imports errors
    imports runtime
    imports runtime/internal/atomic
    imports runtime
```

Is there eny problem in my local env or is there any way how to fix this?

```
go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/radek/Projekty/Go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/radek/Software/Go/go1.6"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/radek/Software/Go/go1.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: did you run `go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint`?

Comment: Yes.I've also tried to update all packages in my GOPATH by `go get -u all`, but it was a blind shot and did not work.

Comment: How did you install Go 1.6? Also, can you include the output of `which go`?

Comment: Just unpacked the binary and changed GOROOT.  This happend to me for go 1.6. If I changed back to 1.5.3 everything works ok.

Comment: but are you sure you're running `$GOROOT/bin/go` and not an older version?

Comment: If you are running the correct binary, with the correct env variables, it's possible you have a /vendor directory caught in there. You can try building with go1.5.3 and `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1` set and see if you have the same error.

Comment: Thanks guys, seems that I did not update the PATH variable to go binaries. Well I feel pretty lame now. Reboot worked, since the terminal loaded the env variables from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this happen to me the other day. It had something to do with my environment variables being setup wrong.

do `go version` and check that you are building with the expected go distribution.

If it's not the version you were expecting, make sure you update your `$GOROOT` and or `$GOPATH` variables to the correct settings.

https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a specific answer to the question. If it is and I can't understand why, then I guess you should explain the relation better.

Comment: This happened quite awhile ago so I can't remember the details. That being said, I believe if your PATH (or other go vars) point to a different Go version, then the imports get confused at build time and leads to the cycles. Setting the env variables properly avoids the issue.

Comment: In my case the problem was something much less complicated: a package was importing itself.

Comment: Yes, that's what the error message describes. But that is not what was wrong in this particular case. Usually when you see that error, you have an import cycle, however in this particular question's case it was an environment variable misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

This error is what is shown when **there is a package importing itself**. For example, in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/myawesome/mistakes`, you have a file that like this:

```
package mistakes

import (
    "github.com/myawesome/mistakes"
)

func CreateComplicatedBugFromSimpleMistake(m mistakes.Mistake) {
    // done.
}
```

That was what I was doing. You should know how to solve it, if this is your case too.

Comment: Yes this case is clear to me. The problem there was some kind of mixed versions in my local env when I migrate from 1.5 to 1.6 and didn't refresh the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the output of `readlink -f $(which go)` and `echo $GOROOT` and if they are different, you should set $GOROOT to point to the root directory of the go binary you are running or vice versa.